# Module Not Found error : no module named 'pyperclip'

Tags: python, selenium, pyperclip

Tryin to install pyperclip into python

1. Using

- Mac 11.2.2(20D80)
- VScode

2. Tried

- pip install pyperclip
- pip3 install pyperclip
- sudo pip install pyperclip
- made virtual space and tried above

Saids **"Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in ./selenium/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.8.2)"**

but when I write code `import pyperclip` and run python,
it still saids Module Not Found Error : No module named 'pyperclip'

please help!
what am I missing?

Comment: have you tried a standalone .py file with import pyperclip in it.

Comment: Can you show us your code where you wrote `import pyperclip` ?

Comment: Which IDE you are working on ?